# Number of words in a textarea always returning 11

Tags: jquery, keyup

I have a short routine that is supposed to get the number of words that are in a textarea and then output that number to the `target`. However, it always returns 11, no matter how many words there actually are.

I'm sure it's something simple, but I cannot see for looking, so if someone could give me some pointers I'd be grateful. Thanks.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var target = $('.dd-options #wp-word-count .word-count');

    jQuery('textarea#welcome_text').on('keyup', function(){

        var text = $(this).val,
            word_count = $.trim(text).split(' ').length;

        target.html(word_count);

    });

});
```

Comment: simple trick for next time: just `console.log()` all the values in question: `this`, `text` and `word_count` and you will spot the error.

Comment: @Christoph: Or better yet, use the debugger built into (or available for) any browser that supports `console.log` and step through the code, examining things as necessary. :-)

Comment: @both - Good point. I was using Firebug, but I couldn't figure out what was going on (looking for something far more complicated than was actually the problem!!). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's `val` is a *function*, so you have to call it (by putting `()` after it):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var target = $('.dd-options #wp-word-count .word-count');

    jQuery('textarea#welcome_text').on('keyup', function(){

        var text = $(this).val(), // <====================== here
            word_count = $.trim(text).split(' ').length;

        target.html(word_count);

    });

});
```

What your code was doing was calling `toString` (implicitly) on a function (which in most browsers returns some version of the function's source code), and then counting the "words" in that.

Side note: In this case, since you're trying to get the value of a `textarea`, you can also just use the `textarea`'s built-in `value` property instead of jQuery's `val` function:

```
var text = this.value,
```

rather than

```
var text = $(this).val(),
```

The `value` property on `textarea` (and `input`) elements is quite reliable cross-browser.

Comment: Ah, thank you - I knew it would be simple! All working as expected now. Thanks.